# checkbox non boolean value?

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jLkxG/6/

The is_checked property can have 2 values: Yes or No. The checkbox should be checked if the value is yes and when the saved link is clicked, the property should be assigned yes or no depending on whether checkbox is checked.

How would you do this in knockoutjs?

Comment: Did you link to the wrong jsfiddle? It doesn't seem to be related to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way besides computed is to use "subscribe" to listen in on the value change. For example, bind to the is_checked and make that value true or false. Then subscribe to that observable and set another property to Yes/No as needed. See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/johnpapa/jLkxG/8/

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkedvals.is_checked"/>
<label>Test</label><br/>

<pre data-bind="text:displayJS">
</pre>​
```

JavaScript

```
var viewModel = (function() {
    var self = this;
    self.checkedvals = {
        is_checked : ko.observable(true),
        is_checked_val : ko.observable("Yes")
    };
    self.checkedvals.is_checked.subscribe(function(){
        self.checkedvals.is_checked_val(self.checkedvals.is_checked() ? "Yes" : "No");
    });

    self.displayJS = ko.computed(function() {
        return JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(checkedvals), null, 2);
    });
})();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
```

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you missed the brackets on your binding:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" data-bind="checked: is_checked() == 'Yes'"/>
```

Now the checkbox will be correctly checked on load.

The larger problem is that clicking the checkbox won't write the value back. If you change is_checked() to a bool, it'll work fine. So if you have:

```
 self.is_checked = ko.observable(true);
```

and

```
data-bind="checked: is_checked"
```

It'll work. Unchecking the box will update the value of is_checked. If it really is important to you that it be Yes/No rather than True/False then you are going to have to write some code to translate the true/false check state into Yes/No. There are a few ways you could go about this. I'd try a computed observable. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/jLkxG/7/